# Fish access non-aliased command from alias

Tags: shell, fish

How can I access the non-aliased version of a command from within the alias for that command? In bash, I can do something like `alias ls='\ls -l'` to access the non-aliased `ls` inside this alias for `ls`. How can I do this in fish?

Right now I'm using `env` to get the executable for the command, but is there a better way?
`alias man='PAGER="bat -p" /usr/bin/env man'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple cases, fish's `alias` will figure it out itself.

You can just do `alias ls='ls -l'` and it will result in the following function:

```
 function ls --description 'alias ls=ls -l'
     command ls -l $argv
 end
```

because

1. fish's `alias` is a cheesy wrapper that defines functions
2. the way to call a command by name, skipping functions and builtins, is to use `command`

So you can do

```
alias man='PAGER="bat -p" command man'
```

(similary, `builtin foo` calls the builtin "foo", skipping any functions)

In this specific case the best solution is to just set $MANPAGER, skipping the alias entirely:

```
set -gx MANPAGER "bat -p"
```

Also, you can avoid any issues with fish's aliases by directly defining a function yourself:

```
function man
     PAGER="bat -p" command man $argv
end
```

or using an [abbreviation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/interactive.html#abbreviations) instead.